# Fastest way to transpose this table while doing an operation

Tags: python, pandas

I have this:

```
name phenotype
ID1      tall
ID2      tall
ID3     short
ID4      tall
```

I want this:

```
ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4 phenotype
yes  yes   no  yes      tall
no   no  yes   no     short
```

I have tried this approach:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['ID1', 'ID2', 'ID3', 'ID4'], 'phenotype' : ['tall', 'tall', 'short', 'tall']})

sample_dict = {}
for sample in df['name']:
    var_list = []
    for variant in df['phenotype'].unique():
        sample_subset = df[df['name'] == sample]
        if variant in sample_subset['phenotype'].to_list():
            var_list.append('yes')
        else:
            var_list.append('no')

        sample_dict[sample] = var_list
sample_dict['phenotype'] = ['tall', 'short']
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(sample_dict)
```

Is there a better and faster to transpose this table while performing the operation I describe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [`pd.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab):

```py
print(
    pd.crosstab(df["phenotype"], df["name"])
    .replace({0: "no", 1: "yes"})
    .reset_index()
    .rename_axis("", axis=1)
)
```

Prints:

```
  phenotype  ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4
0     short   no   no  yes   no
1      tall  yes  yes   no  yes
```